# Post request with parameters and a file on c# compact framework (CF)

Tags: c#, php, post, compact-framework

ive searched through the web and google but i couldn't find how to POST to a php file in C#, COMPACT FRAMEWORK.

I managed to do what i need in C# .net 4.5 framework but couldn't make it work on Compact Framework.

Basicly i need to send a file as a file(what i mean is not the file text if its a text file) so i fetch it with $_FILE on PHP.

With the file i also need to POST some parameters.

with the post i need to send user id password and the file.

thank you very much! :)

EDIT -

i tryed only this for using POST but it doesn't work on Compact Framework(Works perfectly on .net 4+)

```
       openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                string field = textBox3.Text;
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(field);
                //byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(contents);
                MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
                field = textBox4.Text;
                byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(field);
                MemoryStream a = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
                var client = new HttpClient();
                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                content.Add(new StreamContent(s), "userid");
                content.Add(new StreamContent(a), "pwd");
                content.Add(new StreamContent(File.Open(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open)), "file", openFileDialog1.SafeFileName);
                var result = client.PostAsync("http://myurl.com/writefile.php", content);
                Console.WriteLine(result.Result.ToString());
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your comment,
I edited my post above and i added what ive been trying

Comment: "doesn't work" is a bit vague.  Can you tell us how it didn't work?  doesn't compile due to line X, crashes at line Y, etc?  Help us help you.